# Prolog - recursive predicate to output stars 5-1 then back again 1-5

Tags: prolog

I have the below recursive predicates that outputs asterisks from 1-5. Could someone tell me how I would also do the reverse of this so something like the below expected output is what I am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Expected output

```
*****
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Actual Output

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Code

```
asterisk :- asterisk(0, 5).

asterisk(A, B) :- A < B, count(0, A), A1 is A+1, asterisk(A1, B).
asterisk(A, B) :- A >= B.

num(X, Y) :- X =< Y, write('*'), X1 is X+1, num(X1,Y).
num(X, Y) :- X > Y, nl.1
```

Comment: There are a few issues. There are no functions in Prolog, just predicates. Your code doesn't appear to call the `num/2` predicate from the `asterisk/2` predicate. And there's no query in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution. I've created two predicates, one to print the upper and one to print the lower part.

```
printAsterisk(0):-
    nl.
printAsterisk(I):-
    I \= 0,
    write("*"),
    I1 is I-1,
    printAsterisk(I1).

printLower(N,N).
printLower(N,I):-
    I \= N,
    printAsterisk(I),
    I1 is I+1,
    printLower(N,I1).

printUpper(_,0).
printUpper(N,I):-
    I \= 0,
    printAsterisk(I),
    I1 is I-1,
    printUpper(N,I1).

asterisk(N):-
    N1 is N+1,
    printUpper(N,N),
    printLower(N1,1).
```

Query: `?-asterisk(5).`

```
*****
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Thanks @damianodamiano great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
?- asterisk(5).

build(0) :- nl.
build(N) :-
    N>0,
    write("*"),
    N2 is N-1,
    build(N2).

asterisk(0).
asterisk(N) :-
    N>0,
    build(N),
    N2 is N-1,
    asterisk(N2),
    build(N).
```

I get:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
asterisk(I,Z) :-
    length(Ls, I),
    bagof(X, between(1, I, X), Is),
    maplist(length, Ls, Is),
    append(Ls, L),
    maplist(is_asterisk, L),
    reverse(Ls, RLs),
    append(RLs, Ls, Z).

is_asterisk('*').
```

This constructs the list of rows of asterisks. If you then want to print it to `STDOUT`, you can use this:

```
asterisk(I) :-
    asterisk(I, Z),
    maplist(print_row, Z).

print_row(L) :-
    maplist(print, L),
    nl.
```